# Check if server are reachable

Tags: excel, database, vba

I using the below code to connect on a database with VBA. Is there a way to check when the server is down and import a line of code to get a message box for that?

```
Public Const DbCn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=10.10.10.10;Database=dbTest;Uid=user;Pwd=1234567890;"

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rs
    .Open SqlStr, DbCn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    If Not .EOF Then

    End If
    .Close
End With
Set rs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trap an error when connecting to db:

```
'enable to catch an error
on error resume next
'attempt to connect to db
rs.Open SqlStr, DbCn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
'if there's an error when connecting to db, do whatever you want to do
if err.number <> 0 then msgbox err.number
'reset error handling procedure
on error goto 0
```

There might be a better solution but this works for me.